# iTerm2: Export session to text/pdf file

Tags: iterm2

I just recently switched from the default terminal where I was able to export a session to a document file, and I can't find the same option on iTerm2.

An alternative that I have tried based on my searches on the internet:

1) Turned on automatic session logs where it will log the activity of a session.

Problems with this: The saved log will have random spaces, random formatting, and weird texts in between what I write, such as "[k" in between my words.

Does anyone know how to export a session on iTerm2 similarly to the built in terminal?

And, no I don't want to consider cmd+a, cmd+s. I want to know how to properly export a session into a file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PDF Export: Terminal's `Shell` / `Print` equals iTerm's `Shell` / `Print` / `Buffer`

[image]

Comment: Hello @SushiHangover, thank you for replying. I have tried your suggestion, and this doesn't export a session into a pdf file -- it tries to print the session by sending it to a printer.

Comment: @MitterHai Yes, "Print to PDF", lower left hand side of any macOS printer dialog

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover, thanks for the follow up. I followed your instructions and was able to export the file as intended. You are awesome! Thanks again!

Answer (score 25):

In the menu bar:

**Session > Log > Save Contents**

Choose **RTF** as the file type.

Open the file in any Rich Text editor.

[image: Video of the save process]

Comment: It's 3 months later and I'm now realized that I misread text/pdf as text/rtf. Oops.

Comment: This is the best answer to save iterm2 contents in a plain text file.